# How to align a label with radio button on same line in Bootstrap Vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to have the label inlined with its radio buttons:

```
<b-form-group label="Zobrazit">
  <b-form-radio-group id="radio-group-2" v-model="absoluteValues" name="radio-sub-component">
    <b-form-radio value="true">Hodnoty</b-form-radio>
    <b-form-radio value="false">Procenta</b-form-radio>
  </b-form-radio-group>
</b-form-group>
```

It looks this way:

[image]

I cannot find any relevant attribute in [FormGroup](https://bootstrap-vue.netlify.app/docs/components/form-group/) element. The `Label-align` aligns the text but it does not merge both lines.

Update:

`label-col=1` puts all on the same row but the radios are not vertically aligned:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried label-col https://bootstrap-vue.netlify.app/docs/components/form-group/?

Comment: Thanks, this is close. See updated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply pt-2 Bootstrap padding utility class to b-form-radio-group component to make it all on the same line

**Try this:**

```
 <b-form-group label-cols-sm="1" label="Zobrazit">
  <b-form-radio-group class="pt-2" id="radio-group-2" v-model="absoluteValues" 
    name="radio-sub-component">
    <b-form-radio value="true">Hodnoty</b-form-radio>
    <b-form-radio value="false">Procenta</b-form-radio>
  </b-form-radio-group>
</b-form-group>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: The same works for me, but I actually don't understand why it is necessary to explicitly add the top-padding.

Answer (score 0):

Try using plain prop

<b-form-radio-group plain
...